# ggtern (and ggplot) not seeing data in reactive Markdown script

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown, ternary

I have been creating ternary plots in R Markdown using the package ggtern.  I am using R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety" on Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit).  I am working within R Studio Version 0.99.489.

I want to switch from printing each plot individually to using an embedded reactive script (inputSelect and renderPlot functions).  However, using ggtern within renderPlot I get an error that the dataframe I am calling cannot be found.  I've done a number of tests... (1) I can call the same dataframe to renderTable, (2) I can call the same dataframe to renderPlot with base plot function (just X & Y data, ignoring Z), but ggplot gives the same "object 'yourdata' cannot be found".

I've tried switching out of R Markdown to just write (and then call) a separate Shiny app, but that gives similar errors.

Can anyone explain what is going on and suggest a solution?  I have a lot of these to make and my short-term fix is to run some code that loops ggtern to print the 100+ plots to png files and then use a reactive script to select and call the images.  But this obviously is less than ideal!  I could also try using the ternary plot options in packages compositions or robCompositions - but would prefer plotting with ggtern, if possible.

Below are the data and reactive code chunks from my R Markdown document.  I've also published the entire document (https://kdvdecisionanalysis.shinyapps.io/WhyCantPlot) where you can see the various tests that work and don't work.  Thanks!

````
```{r data.import}
# Here is a very small example of input data
triadR <- data.frame(NarrID = rep(1:5, 2), Var = c(rep("Important",5),rep("Law", 5)), X = c(14.15406, 58.15887, 11.79224, 53.37626, 24.08851, 17.53618, 21.94300,  8.92137, 49.28843, 58.15012), Y = c(74.24623, 24.49748, 18.96985, 24.49748, 52.63819, 69.22111, 58.66835, 32.53769, 33.54272, 14.94975), Z = c(11.59971, 17.34365, 69.23792, 22.12626, 23.27329, 13.24271, 19.38865, 58.54094, 17.16886, 26.90012), Ax = rep(0.5,10),   Ay = rep(0.5, 10), DNA = rep(NA, 10))
triadR[3,3:5] = NA
triadQ <- data.frame(Var=c("Important", "Law"), Triad=c("People acted according to", "Justice was achieved through"), X = c("Intuition", "Reconciliation"), Y=c("Logic", "Revenge"), Z=c("Values", "Deterence"), Project=c(1,1))
triadQ
triadR
```
````

This is the plot that I want to make.  The ggtern commands generate the correct plot outside of a Shiny renderPlot command.

````
```{r ggtern, echo=TRUE, fig.width=4}
inputPanel(
selectInput("Triad", "Which triad would you like to view?", levels(unique(triadQ$Triad)))
)

renderPlot({
library(ggtern)
varname <- as.character(triadQ[which(triadQ$Triad==input$Triad),triadQ$Var]$Var)
data_nas <- data.frame(triadR[which(triadR$Var==varname),])
ggtern(data = plotdata, aes(plotdata$X, plotdata$Y, plotdata$Z)) +
    geom_density_tern(n = 200, aes(fill  = ..level.., alpha = ..level..)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(x="Stable",y="Emergent",z="Unstable",title="Fit Together") +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue",high = "red") +
    guides(color = "none", fill = "none", alpha = "none")
})
````

Comment: Maybe you should use `data_nas` instead of `plotdata`

Comment: So where exactly was `plotdata` defined? I think you are getting confused because variables stay defined in a R -Studio session during development, but each R-markdown invocation clears the session.

Comment: I think substituting `data_nas` with `plotdata` will fix things like HuberL suggested, but I can't really test it as the new version of `ggplot` seems to have broken `ggtern`

Comment: So `ggtern` appears to be broken as of `ggplot 2.0.0`

Comment: Sorry, yes, in transcribing a small example from my real code, I did miss the `plotdata` line in one of the code chunks.  In the real code, I do invoke the correct data at each chunk.  But I get the same error regardless.  If it is just the ggplot update, that is unfortunate!  Thanks for responses.

Comment: I have just published ggtern 2.0.1, essentially a completely re-written package to work with ggplot2 2.0.0. Try your code after upgrading, let me know if you still have issues. Here is a brief overview of some of the features: http://ahref.io/UuED1